# edittext maxlength set 7 but accept 6?

Tags: android, android-edittext, maxlength

I use maxlengnth for edittext, I set it 7 altough it allows to input 6 characters.
It only allow 6 caharcters, instead of 7...

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        style="@style/txtstyle"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="7" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

java code

```
txt_phonenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
txt_phonenumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

What is the best and simplest working way for character limit?

Comment: Do you mean that it allows max 6 character instead of 7, or do you mean that you don't want to allow 6 characters?

Comment: it does not allow 7 chars with these codes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quick search and little testing I found the following

just remove

```
txt_phonenumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

this line. Why because `The formatting is based on the current system locale and future locale changes may not take effect on this instance`. For more detail see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html). After removing this line you can enter 7 digits.

I hope this wil help you.